# Celery concurrency configuration for io/cpu bound task

Tags: python, concurrency, celery

I have tasks that need to load a few large files from the internet and then do some processing. Running synchronously the loading would take ~3s and the processing ~0.2s. Although the processing is much faster than loading, it still takes a considerable amount of time.

I wonder what would be the best celery configuration to handle my scenario. Multi-processing, Eventlet, or maybe something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question seems to me it needs an answer comparing multi-process/thread versus green threads; however, generally speaking in the context of celery concurrency, in doesn't make a difference using either, unless you have limited resources (and too many tasks), or you are making too many outbound connections and you are i/o-bound, then you will have to go "green" and use eventlet.

A good idea, I have seen Instagram presenting in last PyCon 2013 ([Messaging at Scale at Instagram](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E708csv4XgY#t=140)), they use both. The main usage is the threaded tasks, yet, they use the "green" approach with those tasks that does nothing but doing outbound request to other websites, like twitter, facebook, and tumbler .. those type of tasks don't deserve a complete thread/process, as no real processing happening, moveover, the request/respones cycle takes some time, so, the best thing to do with those tasks is to make them green.

You can create worker(s) that use thread/process per task, that only process tasks through specific queues, and another worker(s) that uses greenlets that only process other tasks through other queues. Then you can decide which goes where as per the above explanation!

Comment: Thanks. I considered mixing thread/process workers, or maybe running multiple thread workers on the same machine. However, I was hoping there is some kind of a built-in solution.

Comment: @Xyand, You're welcome .. the eventlet is already supported in celery, you can choose to make it multi-threaded or greenlet.. if you mean something else please let me know.

Comment: @Xyand, btw, running multiple workers on the same machine is normal, you can run more than one worker and control them all using `celeryd_multi`, it will help you to do so easily.